# pydev Ipython console freezing when paging

Tags: pydev, ipython

If in the pydev 2.5 with Ipython console 0.11 I write:

```
import numpy

numpy?
```

I get the documentation for numpy and as it's longer than the screen it gets paged showing the message:

```
---Return to continue, q to quit---
```

However no matter what keys I press it'll stay there. typically I'll have to restart the console to continue.

Is this a bug?

Comment: It sounds like something that should be fixed, though I'm not sure how pydev's console works. Please [report it as an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: This behaviour only happens within pydev interactive console. If I run an ipython outside eclipse the paging works as expected. Maybe a pydev issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the console is not sending the key press to actually perform the paging.

A workaround is to redefine the ipython paging function to never actually page.
Add the following code to the 'Initial interpreter commands'  (PyDev -> Interactive Console)

```
from IPython.core import page
def nopage(strng, start=0, screen_lines=0, pager_cmd=None):
    print(strng)
page.page = nopage
```